# Download official Samsung phone firmware

Tags: samsung, device-firmware, radio-firmware

Does Samsung provides official firmware (old phones included)? I have found only user manuals on the web page. I'm looking for equivalent of Google's https://developers.google.com/android/images which allows full reinstallation with Linux (I know that fastboot was replaced by Odin, thus I'll have to use https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall).

I've found these sites, but these aren't official, right?

- https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/
- https://www.sammobile.com/
- https://updato.com/

The reason I want is that I'd like to test postmarketOS (https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_J5_2016_(samsung-j5x)) and then I'd like to revert back.

UPDATE: the question is not "which tool should I use" (although that is useful to know), but "what is the official URL for downloading images. Is there any for updating by user clicking on the web page? (there might be just REST/other API for devices).

Looking at

- [SamloaderKotlin](https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin):

  - https://www.odinrom.com/samsung/ (https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin/blob/9fee3940855d1a4cd565ae2f6896cdb0ee826782/common/src/commonMain/kotlin/tk/zwander/common/util/Firmware.kt#L27)
  - https://fota-cloud-dn.ospserver.net:443/firmware/ (https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin/blob/9fee3940855d1a4cd565ae2f6896cdb0ee826782/common/src/commonMain/kotlin/tk/zwander/common/util/Firmware.kt#L45)
  - https://neofussvr.sslcs.cdngc.net (https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin/blob/9fee3940855d1a4cd565ae2f6896cdb0ee826782/common/src/commonMain/kotlin/tk/zwander/common/tools/FusClient.kt#L76-L89), document: "Make a request to Samsung, automatically inserting authorization data." - is this really Samsung official?
- [samloader](https://github.com/samloader/samloader) (already deprecated):

  - https://fota-cloud-dn.ospserver.net/firmware/ (https://github.com/samloader/samloader/blob/95d2ac8fb9027b7908d201e4ce807a5b338f923a/samloader/versionfetch.py#L20)
  - http://cloud-neofussvr.sslcs.cdngc.net (https://github.com/samloader/samloader/blob/95d2ac8fb9027b7908d201e4ce807a5b338f923a/samloader/fusclient.py#L40)
  - https://neofussvr.sslcs.cdngc.net/ (https://github.com/samloader/samloader/blob/95d2ac8fb9027b7908d201e4ce807a5b338f923a/samloader/fusclient.py#L19)

Comment: There are local tools that directly load Samsung firmware files from Samsung download servers. [Samloader](https://github.com/samloader/samloader) is (or was?) a very popular tool. Now there are other tools like [Samloader Kotlin](https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin).

Comment: Thanks for adding Kotlin version, I knew only the original Samloader. I updated the question, because I really want to know the URL of the official storage. Without that how can I trust the tools they are downloading the official?

Comment: Unless you have unlocked the bootloader (or better has allowed to unlock it in developer options) Android devices will not allow to install non-matching or modified firmware.

Comment: @Robert Yes, that's true (I've done it on several non-Samsung aosp based devices), but how is it related to the question of official URL?

Comment: Well if you have an genuine original firmware it can be installed, if not the device will refuse to install it. So in the end after tryna Ng to install a downloaded firmware you will know if it is an original one or not. I know that this is not a good solution but I don't know how to verify a Samsung firmware offline (without device). As Samsung does not provide official download servers with a web UI I don't see an alternative than to trust samloader and successors.

Comment: Did you ever get Heimdall to work? It never worked for me ...